# Chessboardjs NPM package, not showing images

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, npm, chessboard.js

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/chessboardjs package with meteor 1.13. I wrote simple react component to render the board, but it doesn't render images for some reason. The compoent code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ChessBoard from 'chessboardjs'

export default class GamePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="chessboard" style={{"width": "400px"}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var board = ChessBoard('chessboard');
    }
}
```

I see that .css from that package is not being used, so maybe I have to import it as well somehow?

Answer (score 1):

So the assets for chessboard.js are stored somewhere in static, right? There's a question out there about `Flask` which might have your answer,

[Integrate chessbord.js with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136916/integrate-chessbord-js-with-flask)

The idea is to modify the `chessboard.js` library, where it `src` the images for the board.

Remember to clear your cache if it's not working, as the browser will hold onto to the unedited library.

Comment: They should be installed 'node_modules/chessboardjs/www/' https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/tree/master/www